# Is this expression correct for the probability of the union of four events?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Searching on google, I could not find a general expression for the probability of the union of four events $A,B,C,D$. I will be grateful if this relation is not correct, someone please correct it.
$$   P (A\cup B\cup C\cup D)=\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\\
P (A) + P (B) + P (C) + P (D) \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\\
 -P (A \cap  B) - P (A \cap 
 D) - P (B \cap C) - P (C \cap D) \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \\
 +P (A \cap B\cap C)
+P (A\cap B \cap D) + P (A \cap C \cap 
 D) + P (B \cap C \cap D)  \qquad\qquad\qquad\\
-P (A  \cap B  \cap C  \cap 
D)  \qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\quad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad $$

Comment: When you write $P(A) \cap P(B)$, do you mean $P(A \cap B)$? Similar for the other expressions.

Comment: What does "mutually inclusive" mean?

Comment: You're missing some terms (unless you know e.g. $A$ and $C$ are mutually exclusive). This is known as the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Comment: @Martha97  That's a very eccentric use of terminology.  Why not just say that you have four events with no further information regarding their intersections?

Comment: For the problem, just look up Inclusion Exclusion, the formula is standard.  Yours is incorrect (as it omits $A\cap C$ and $B\cap D$).

Comment: @lulu Are the signs of the intersection part (lines 2,3,4 after the equality sign) are correct?

Comment: You have to consider intersections of any $2$ sets taken from the $4$ available, meaning there should be a total of $\binom42=6$ terms.

Comment: As you'll see from the general formula, the sign is determined by the parity of the number of terms you are intersecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
& {} -P (A \cap  B) - P (A \cap D) - P (B \cap C) \\[6pt]
& {} - P (C \cap D) - \text{two other terms}
\end{align}
Here are the terms involving intersections of two sets:
\begin{align}
& 
{} -P (A \cap  B) - P (A \cap D) - P (B \cap C) \\[6pt]
& {} - P (C \cap D) - P(A\cap C) - P(B\cap D)
\end{align}